# Is there a way to blacklist certain terms from triggering these suggestions

Tags: google-search-appliance

Issue: GSA is providing "Did you mean" suggestions that I would like to disable. For instance, a search for "void cheque" is returning "avoid cheque". In the banking domain, this would been seen as a somewhat silly suggestion. :)

I cannot find anything in the documentation that suggests this is possible, so I am asking the group here...

Is there a way to blacklist certain terms from triggering these suggestions?

Comment: Google also has a natural blacklist to block swearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the "Query Expansion Policy", if you use "Local" or "Full" query expansion, you can also use a blacklist to block expansion of specified terms.

`Search > Search Features > Query Settings`

Source:

https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/serve_filters.html#query_expansion

https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/serve_query_expansion.html#uploadqe

Answer (score 0):

You can import a black list specific to suggestions.  (Query expansion black listing is for another purpose).  See documentation for specific form of import list.  (note: you can't seed the list)

https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/admin_console_help/serve_suggestions.html#importing_sb